# Embedded Jetty with annotated servlet patterns?

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty, servlet-3.0

The following working code demonstrates including two servlets into an embedded instance of jetty.

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
context.setContextPath("/");
context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new Html()), "/html");
context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new Iphone()), "/iphone");       
server.setHandler(context);
server.start();
server.join();
```

How should this be altered so that instead of using the url "/iphone", it would use the urlpatterns in the annotation of the servlet, ie

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/json", "/iphone"})
public class Iphone extends HttpServlet {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The servlets are on your server's classpath rather than packaged in a WAR.

[Servlet 3.0 specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315) states:

> In a web application, classes using annotations will have their
>   annotations processed  only if they are located in the
>   `WEB-INF/classes` directory, or if they are packaged  in a jar file
>   located in `WEB-INF/lib` within the application.
>
> The web application deployment descriptor contains a new
>   “`metadata-complete`” attribute on the web-app element. The
>   “`metadata-complete`” attribute defines  whether the web descriptor is
>   complete, or whether the class files of the jar file should be
>   examined for annotations and web fragments at deployment time. If
>   “`metadata-complete`” is set to "`true`", the deployment tool MUST
>   ignore any servlet annotations present in the class files of the
>   application and web fragments. If the metadata-complete attribute is
>   not specified or is set to "false", the deployment tool must examine
>   the class files of the application for annotations, and scan for web
>   fragments.

You may have to look at packaging a WAR and using a context with more features like [`WebAppContext`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.html).

Alternatively, you might try your own annotation scanning. Something of the form:

```
void registerServlets(ServletContextHandler context,
                              Class<? extends HttpServlet> type)
          throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
                 InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
    WebServlet info = type.getAnnotation(WebServlet.class);
    for (String pattern : info.urlPatterns()) {
        HttpServlet servlet = type.getConstructor().newInstance();
        context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(servlet), pattern);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if it is a debug build and IDE places classes outside of WEB-INF/classes?

Comment: @RobertVažan It is likely that the annotations will not be scanned in your case for the reasons described above.

Comment: Second link is dead.

Comment: The annotation Scanner is a really interesting concept, but it did not work for me. The annotations were processed, but were not available for service.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer here: [Embedded Jetty does not find Annotated Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674206/embedded-jetty-does-not-find-annotated-servlet/41838197#41838197)

In short, you need to:

1. set the necessary configurations as stated in the answer
2. force Jetty to scan the classes/ directory where the compiled servlets go. By default it only scans jars I think.