# Embedded Jetty: Dependency Injection not occurring

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, cdi, embedded-jetty

Apologies for the long post.  Do not know when is too much.  The issue is that dependency injection is not occurring on Jersey REST servlet. Using Embedded Jetty and REST as required by the product designer.
Here is some of the code I have:

AppServer.java

```
Configuration.ClassList classList = Configuration.ClassList.setServerDefault(server);
classList.addAfter("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration",
        "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration",
        "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration");
classList.addBefore("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration",
        "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration");

ServletContextHandler servletCtx = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
servletCtx.setContextPath("/rest/v1");
ServletHolder jerseyServlet = servletCtx.addServlet(
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class
        , "/*");
jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);

jerseyServlet.setInitParameter(
        "jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",
        MbiResource.class.getCanonicalName());

WebAppContext webAppCtx = new WebAppContext();
webAppCtx.setResourceBase("webapp");
webAppCtx.setContextPath("/");

HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{servletCtx,webAppCtx,new DefaultHandler()});

server.setHandler(handlers);
```

RestResource.java

```
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("mbi")
@Consumes({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class MbiResource {
    **//this does not work**
    @Resource(mappedName = "jdbc/warehouse-datasource")
    DataSource dataSource;

    @GET
    public String get(){
    **//this does work**
        try{
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            dataSource = (DataSource) ic.lookup("jdbc/warehouse-datasource");
            return dataSource.toString();
        }catch (Exception ex){
            return ex.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

POM (The reason for all dependencies is to force the same version)

```
<jetty.version>9.4.35.v20201120</jetty.version>        
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
  <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-jndi</artifactId>
  <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-jsp</artifactId>
  <version>9.2.30.v20200428</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
  <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
  <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
  <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
  <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
  <version>9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

These are some of the references I used to research this issue.

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#advanced-embedding

[How to embed Jetty and Jersey into my Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953886/how-to-embed-jetty-and-jersey-into-my-java-application)

[Embedded Jetty does not find Annotated Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674206/embedded-jetty-does-not-find-annotated-servlet)

[Jersey jdbc @resource not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831611/jersey-jdbc-resource-not-working)

Comment: You need to either try to enable [CDI support](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/cdi.support.html#cdi.support.existing.containers) or use HK2 to create a custom injection.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I will try that.  It would help if I asked the right question.